# Merging multiple jacoco agent reports to be used by SONAR?

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm running custom parallel system tests across multiple vm's and performing runtime analysis on our compiled application using the jacoco agent. Each of these agents will generate their own report.exec, with corresponding coverage, and we want a way to represent overall "integration test" coverage for the project (in SONAR) as a whole.

This endeavor is still in the planning phase, so I'm doing my best to create a road map. I understand that ant/maven builds make report merging easy, however it is a requirement that the jacoco *agent* be used to generate runtime coverage due to the nature of our test environment.

I've searched high and low for a solution that applies to this situation but it seems like almost every problem that falls into this jacoco/sonar category has its own unique conditions, and almost nobody has any interest in using the jacoco agent.

The agents will be running in tcpserver mode with a master client responsible for orchestrating dumps and report output. If this client is configured to output to a single file, will these reports automatically be appended/merged into one? Does there exist any API or stand-alone project for merging multiple coverage reports that I can integrate into our client that doesn't depend on ant or maven?

Alternatively, is there a SONAR configuration for accepting multiple reports of this nature and merging their coverage by line-of-code? Define each individual report in the parent pom.xml or just give it a path to the folder containing the whole collection and let SONAR sort it out?

I'm willing to accept that there's no easy solution to this problem, but anything short of having to write my own merge functionality would really help get this project off the ground.

E: It's probably worth mentioning that we won't be generating any actual HTML/XML/etc. reports, just exec files which we'll feed to SONAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question has gotten so many views:

The [ExecutionData](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/api/org/jacoco/core/data/ExecutionData.html) object has a merge method. Once all reports have been merged the resulting object can be passed to [ExecutionDataWriter](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/api/org/jacoco/core/data/ExecutionDataWriter.html) and output as normal.

Coverage is an OR comparison so merging coverage of multiple instances of the same software undergoing different tests will be comperhensive.

As far as SONAR goes (depending on your pipeline) you can manually introduce your merged report and as long as the SLOC/binaries are isometric then you'll get a bunch of beautiful red and green bars.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Thx.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Gradle you must first [merge the Jacoco execution](https://cristian.io/post/sonar-coverage/) data and then tell sonarqube to use that instead of the individual `exec` files generated by each submodule.

Here's how it would look like:

```
def allTestCoverageFile = "$buildDir/jacoco/allTestCoverage.exec"

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "your.org:YourProject"
        property "sonar.projectName", "YourProject"
        property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", allTestCoverageFile
    }
}

task jacocoMergeTest(type: JacocoMerge) {
    destinationFile = file(allTestCoverageFile)
    executionData = project.fileTree(dir: '.', include:'**/build/jacoco/test.exec')
}

task jacocoMerge(dependsOn: ['jacocoMergeTest']) {
    // used to run the other merge tasks
}

subprojects {
    sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.jacoco.reportPath", allTestCoverageFile
        }
    }
}
```

In a nutshell:

- First, we define a global coverage file output for our test reports (`allTestCoverageFile`).
- Then we need to tell Sonarqube to use that file (using `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths`). But notice we also have to do it in the subprojects closure. This is extremely important. Don’t miss it.
- Finally, we create a custom task that extends from `JacocoMerge` (an incubating class from the Jacoco plugin), that merges all the test coverage reports from all projects (`executionData`) into our `allTestCoverageFile`.

Answer (score 2):

Caveat: I haven't done this, but the question intrigued me. A search for "jacoco merge exec" turned up these links that look like they should address your problem:

- http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/merge-mojo.html
- http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-34172 (in particular, scroll down to "Playground 3", it seems to be an on target example)

My experience with jacoco (we're using it for unit test coverage with an ant build) suggests that you want to execute your tests in one step, and load to SonarQube in a separate step. So I don't see where it matters whether you're using ant, maven, jacoco agent, or whatever. I expect your process creates jacoco.exec files, and you will then merge them before executing a SonarQube analysis.

Comment: You're right, that situation does apply perfectly. Unfortunately we don't use Ant and I don't think this is enough of a reason to get IT to install it.